# How to ensure a package doesn't break a document because of names clashes?

Tags: packages

I need to add refs to a very old book. This book contains many macros redefined like `\ref`. I'm afraid that adding `hyperref` may break something that is already there. Can I add a package but wrap it somehow like this?

```
namespace N {
    #include "my.h"
}
```

Comment: no you can't. You will have to try if it breaks or not.

Comment: For a typeset document you don't need `hyperref`.

Comment: @PeterWilson what do you call _typeset document_? How can I get clickable references then?

Comment: peter means a book, on paper.  But for your main question there is no namespacing, all package definitions are global. even if theer was namespacing for internal commands, if you have some non standard macros that have redefined `\ref` and then you load hyperref that redefines` \ref` to add hyperlinking., assuming the standard definition, there would be no way without inspecting the code to know what the outcome will be.

Comment: One way to get a sort-of namespace is to replace the redefinition of `\ref` in your old source to `\oldbookref` and also replace all occurences of the command where it is used. This kind of namespace-through-prefix is done by many packages to prevent accidental command name conflicts.